# How to set 12 hours format in a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to change the time format in a DataGridView ?

My requirement is to have a 12 hours format with AM, PM. For example 10:23 am, 10:23 pm. I have tried this:

```
datagridview.column(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm"
```

DGVDWA.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss tt"[image]
but it shows an error popup (it worked in VB.NET Windows form app).

Comment: Try with DGV cellformatting ..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "tt" to the end of your code to set the format:

```
datagridview.column(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss tt"
```

This should display the time as 10:59:01 PM. Remove the :ss if you do not want to display seconds.

More information can be found here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#ttSpecifier)